# How to manipulate templates without copying them, for example in an extension?

Tags: module, magento-1, template

If I write extensions it is often unavoidable  to install small pieces of code into core templates (if there are no appropriate layout templates).

How do you handle this situation? How do to inject code to the templates?

Comment: I know Branko from Inchoo tried to solve this problem as well, while old may still be relevant: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-you-could-build-your-magento-extensions-without-view-files/

Comment: Branko is using the Javascript method as @fab mentions.

Comment: However, I was not talking about DOM with JavaScript, but with PHP.

Comment: @fab, true. I meant Domen Vrankar :-)

Answer (score 2):

My usual approach for this is an observer for `core_block_abstract_to_html_after` that inserts HTML or whole blocks before the original block renders the template.

**Disclaimer: This is not meant to be a swiss army knife, you should always check first, if you cannot make your changes via layout XML!**

*The idea:* observer recognizes block type and rewrites HTML

*Preconditions:* original block is determinable from class and/or block alias (see layout XML).

An observer method would look like this:

```
public function onCoreBlockAbstractToHtmlAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    /* @var $block Mage_Core_Block_Abstract */
    $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
    /* @var $transport Varien_Object */
    $transport = $observer->getEvent()->getTransport();

    if ($block->getBlockAlias() === 'product.info.addtocart'
    && $block instanceof Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View)
    {
        $this->insertIntoProductView($block, $transport);
    }
}
```

Here a check for both, alias and class name occurs. The `$transport` parameter always encapsulates the HTML string, so in `insertIntoProductView()` something like this happens:

```
$html = $transport->getHtml() . 'new code at the end';
$transport->setHtml($html);
```

**Attention:** It is important to assign `$html` at the beginning, before rendering other blocks, because the transport object is shared between all blocks and the original content can get lost. [More info on that phenomen on my blog.](https://www.schmengler-se.de/en/2015/01/magento-block-inhalt-verschwindet-nach-core_block_to_html_after-event/)

There are different variants how the HTML can be modified. Adding code at the end or beginning is of course the simplest one. To change code anywhere in the middle, sometimes regular expressions are useful, but those might be very tightly coupled to the original template. The best way would be [`DOM manipulation`](http://php.net/dom) with a careful use of selectors to stay as theme independent as possible.

Comment: I think the DOM manipulation approach would be a very nice one. Might try this out in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can go for javascript approach - add your template blocks as hidden children of "content" section and then move them in javascript to the location where you would like them to have and remove display: none afterwards.

But still I would almost always go with the usual declare-new-store-theme-and-rewrite-templates-there approach. I usually write all my template code in separate files so that intrusions to other templates is only one line - printing out block html.

Comment: I am having a generic module in mind which could be released to the public - so there is no specific store from my point of view - it should work for all.

Comment: It's certainly not possible to create a one-size-fits-all solution as people can remove class names and ids from DOM and imho it's easier for someone to add lines that print out your blocks to their theme than it is for them to change an awesome injection system that broke because of their changes to their theme. I'd say that it's better to encapsulate your html in your own theme files (no matter how small they are), ship with modified default theme files (adding only block html printing code to them) that can be used for reference and not confuse people with needless abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

Coming across this question, I've often felt conflicted here. On one hand, template files are *meant* to be modified, right? That's why they are there. Should simple modifications be done in a template or by modifying backend data? I have had this conversation a number of times, it usually goes something like:

> Backend developer: Why are you modifying the template? My code no longer works!
>
> Frontend developer: I need to add a new feature and modifying the template is simple enough and doesn't require another developer to create data for me!

They're both valid arguments.

That said, reading through the comments in the Inchoo article mentioned by @B00MER, there is one which expresses that their method is effectively a hack, and I agree (despite that it works). He goes on to offer the idea of including a "plug and play" switch as a config value which, when enabled, forces a customized template to be used (which includes the new feature), and when disabled, forces a developer to open the required template and insert the code themselves.

To me, this sounds like a solution that would be most appropriate in many situations, especially when these functions are documented (via the comment for the backend config field) and the template is less likely to already be customized for any given store (ie. the product view template is often customized, so this may not be appropriate; however, the checkout/available shipping method template is much less likely to be modified and this solution would be more appropriate).

Answer (score 0):

Generally the change to the templates should be kept as small as possible in size. For example, define child blocks in the layout XML files and then use

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('foobar') ?>
```

The module then could - besides an useful readme file - contain a script that patches the templates and pulls them to the custom theme if necessary.

Whenever, this can not cover all cases, because templates could have been modified.

Sometimes it is likely that other extensions want to insert code at the same position, so for the future, one should consider to additionally file a pull request for the Magento core to include such `getChildHtml()` points in the template.